# Express.js error with route validated path param via middleware

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I got this middleware for the following route:

```
router.param('userId', (req, res, next, val) => {
            if (!/^\d+$/i.test(val)) {
                globalResponse.sendResponse(res, 400, `la sintaxis de entrada no es válida para integer: «${val}»`, true);
            } else {
                next();
            }
        });
```

the route is :

```
router.get('/user/:userId', (req, res) => {
        let userId = req.params.userId,
            criteria = {};
        criteria.userId = Number(userId);
        users.findUserByCriteria(criteria)
            .then(userFinded => {
                if (userFinded != null) {
                    globalResponse.sendResponse(res, 200, userFinded, false);
                } else {
                    globalResponse.sendResponse(res, 404, `Usuario ${userId} no Encontrado.`, true);
                }
            })
            .catch(err => {
                globalResponse.sendResponse(res, 500, err, true)
            });
    });
```

all ok, the error is when try use other route `'/user/'` the middleware Valid without this the path param `'userId'`

```
router.get('/user/all', (req, res) => {
        users.findAllUsers()
            .then(allUsers => {
                globalResponse.sendResponse(res, 200, allUsers, false);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                globalResponse.sendResponse(res, 500, err, true);
            });
    });
```

then in `'user/all'` valid and this not is necesary

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: the middleware valid '/user/all' and that route not require el param userId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make some changes to accept all parameter

```
 router.param('userId', (req, res, next, val) => {
    if(val=="all")  
   {
    next();
   }else if (!/^\d+$/i.test(val)) {
                    globalResponse.sendResponse(res, 400, "la sintaxis ...", true);
                } else {
                    next();
                }
            });
```

and in your later code

```
 let userId = req.params.userId,
if(userId=="all"){
 users.findAllUsers()
            .then(allUsers => {
                globalResponse.sendResponse(res, 200, allUsers, false);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                globalResponse.sendResponse(res, 500, err, true);
            });
} 

.........
......
```

You dont need this router `router.get('/user/all', (req, res) => {`

Comment: work, but 'all' not is an param, and express take this as one